# How to Create HANA Temp table in Vora Programmatically(Scala)

Tags: vora

At the moment a temp table is created using the following statement

val HANA_TABLE = s"""
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_HANA
USING com.sap.spark.hana
OPTIONS (
  path         "TABLE",
  host         "HANA1",
  dbschema     "SCHEMA",
  user         "USER",
  passwd       "PASSWD",
  instance     "22"
)"""
vc.sql(HANA_TABLE);

Is there a way to do this Programmatically in scala? like
**vc.read.format("com.sap.spark.hana").options(options).loadTemp()**

on a side note is there an API for Vora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the [Vora Developer Guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/hana_vora/SAP_HANA_Vora_Developer_Guide_en.pdf) -> Chapter "8 Accessing Data in SAP HANA"

Your example could be written in this way

```
val options = Map(
  "dbschema" -> "SCHEMA",
  "path"     -> "TABLE",
  "host"     -> "HANA1",
  "instance" -> "22",
  "user"     -> "USER",
  "passwd"   -> "PASSWD"
 ) 

val inputDF = vc.read.format("com.sap.spark.hana").options(options).load()
inputDF.registerTempTable("TEMP_HANA")

vc.sql("select * from TEMP_HANA").show
```